# PostgreSQL Trigram indexes vs btree

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have this searching query for my `cake` database, which is currently very slow and I'm looking to improve it. I am running PostgreSQL v. 9.6.

Table structure:

```
Table: Cakes
=====
id               int
cake_id          varchar
cake_short_name  varchar
cake_full_name   varchar
has_recipe       boolean
createdAt        Datetime
updatedAt        DateTime


Table: CakeViews
=========
id               int
cake_id          varchar
createdAt        Datetime
updatedAt        DateTime
```

**Query:**

```
    WITH myconstants (myquery, queryLiteral) as (
       values ('%a%', 'a')
    )
    
        select
        full_count,
        cake_id,
        cake_short_name,
        cake_full_name,
        has_recipe,
        views
        from (
          select
            count(*) OVER() AS full_count,
            cake_id,
            cake_short_name,
            cake_full_name,
            has_recipe
            cast((select count(*) FROM "CakeViews" as cv where "createdAt" > CURRENT_DATE - 3 and c.cake_id = cv.cake_id) as integer) as views
          from "Cakes" c, myconstants
          where has_recipe = true 
            and (cake_full_name ilike myquery or cake_short_name ilike myquery)
            or cake_full_name ilike lower(queryLiteral) or cake_short_name ilike lower(queryLiteral)) t, myconstants
        order by views desc,
          case
            when cake_short_name ilike lower(queryLiteral) then 1
            when cake_full_name ilike lower(queryLiteral) then 1
          end,
          case
            when has_recipe = true and cake_short_name ilike myquery then length(cake_short_name)
            when has_recipe = true and cake_full_name ilike myquery then length(cake_full_name)
          end
            limit 10
```

I have ideas for the following indices, but they don't speed up the query that much:

```
    CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
    CREATE INDEX idx_cakes_cake_short_name ON public."Cakes" (lower(cake_short_name) varchar_pattern_ops);
    CREATE INDEX idx_cakes_cake_id ON public."Cakes" (cake_short_name);
    
    CREATE INDEX idx_cakeviews_cake_id ON public."CakeViews" (cake_id);
    CREATE INDEX idx_cakes_cake_short_name ON public."Cakes" USING gin (cake_short_name gin_trgm_ops);
    CREATE INDEX idx_cakes_cake_full_name ON public."Cakes" USING gin (cake_full_name gin_trgm_ops);
```

**Questions**:

- What indices would be better or which am I missing?
- Is my query inefficient?

**EDIT**: Explain Analyze output: [here](https://controlc.com/e50faf8a)

Comment: Please provide the output of explain analyze, and the table structures. Also, mention the version of postgres in use

Comment: @HaleemurAli I've updated the question with the information and the output of explain analyse

Comment: what is the relationship between `myquery` & `queryLiteral`? is `myquery` always `queryLiteral` surrounded by `%`?

Comment: also, please update the question with a description of how you expect the results to be sorted by the current order by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query '%a%' doesn't contain any trigrams, so the index will not be useful there.  It must scan the whole table.  But if you used a longer query, then they might be useful.

The index `on "CakeViews" (cake_id)` would be better if it were `on "CakeViews" (cake_id, "createdAt")`.  Except that none of your cakes seem to have any views, so if that is generally the case I guess it wouldn't matter.